# Select query with max quantity in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I want to select the value with max Quantity and at the same time have to insert it into a different table but I'm getting an error. please help me to fix this query. I attached the query I using.

```
<?php

$select = quantity_break::where('quab_price','!=','0')>where('quab_quantity','=',DB::raw('MAX(quab_quantity)'))
->select(array('quab_product_code','quab_quantity_break_level',DB::raw('MAX(quab_quantity) as maxQty'),DB::raw('MIN(quab_price) as MinPrice')))
                    ->groupBy('quab_product_code');

        $bindings = $select->getBindings();

        $insertQuery = 'INSERT into from_price_temp (pro_code,break_level,qty,price) '
            . $select->toSql();

        DB::insert($insertQuery, $bindings);
    
?>
```

**I attached the error screenshot also**

[image]

Comment: Either add `quab_quantity_break_level` to groupBy expression or apply some aggregate functoin to it. Depends on the amount of values matched to each `quab_product_code` value - does it is always 1 or not.

Comment: ->groupBy('quab_product_code','quab_quantity_break_level');

Comment: But still same error

Comment: *But still same error* Impossible - at least the error message part with query citate must be altered. Or you alter in one place but receive error from another.

Comment: If I remove this ->where('quab_quantity','=',DB::raw('MAX(quab_quantity)'))  that sql is working

Comment: You cannot compare separate and aggregated values. Obtain aggregated value in the subquery then compare.